# Replace and execute autotext

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I am new to VBA; I am trying to create an application in which I want to place text and able to execute auto text command (<kbd>F3</kbd> ) when the text is replaced in the document.

My issue is after replacing cursor is lost and I am getting a message that no valid code exists for selection. Can someone please assist.

I am using below code :

```
Sub VbaAutomation()
  With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "-A11"
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
  Wrap:=wdFindContinue   
    .Execute
    SendKeys "{F3}"
  End With
End Sub
```

The better solution can be instead of replacing text and executing code.

I want execute the macro in which it replaces any building block code with auto text code. For example, my word document has `ABCD, CDEF` code and macro automatically iterates through building block code and replace this with exact auto text code paragraphs.

Comment: I don't fully understand your intention but noting that no one seems to want to advise you I venture the question what F3 has to do with what you want to achieve. Your code looks for "-A11" within the selected text and replaces it with "". There is no mention of "building block code" or "auto text code", and if F3 is somehow related to either of these or both, it has no relation with the rest of the code within which it is found. For what it's worth: you should accept that your concept will just allow replacing of "-A11" with "". Nothing more.

Comment: Thanks Yes F3 is to run the auto text and building blocks.I want to replace the -p1 so that I can exeute building blocks

Comment: We are talking past each other. (1) F3 calls a program. In VBA, if you want to call a program, you need to know its name. However, I am pretty sure that the program F3 is calling isn't a VBA macro. Therefore you would have to call it using proper VBA syntax to run the kind of program it is. (2) If you wish to replace placeholders in your document with building blocks you need to specify the building block, find the placeholder and replace. If you can load the building block into the `Replacement.Text` property of the `Find` method you might use a version of your code for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks F3 is used as sendKeys {"F3"}. so bascially I want to replcae text and then execute F3 key on the same time once this is replcaed.

Comment: Did you get `SendKeys "{F3}"` to work without making any changes to the text?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you find and replace with vba. You don't need to use <kbd>F3</kbd>. You have to collect the result of `.Execute`, and iterate as long as you find something.

Try this, to replace every occurrences of `-A11` in current document:

```vb
Sub VbaAutomation()
On Error GoTo ErrorTrap

    Dim i As Long, crazyUpLimit As Long
    Dim isFound As Boolean
    isFound = True
    crazyUpLimit = 1000

    Do While (isFound And i < crazyUpLimit)
        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = "-A11"
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.Text = ""
        ' here is the trick to go on as long as you find
            isFound = .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
        End With
        i = i + 1

    Loop

Exit Sub

FilePatternError:
    MsgBox ActiveDocument.Name & ": unknown patter of document (" & fPattern & " expected)."

Exit Sub
ErrorTrap:
    Beep
    MsgBox "FAILED" & Chr(13) & "Error number: " & err & Chr(13) & Error(err)

End Sub
```

PS: added regular error handling and a `crazyUpLimit` to avoid blocking your PC - it's often useful for myself.

Share & Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Did you automatically execute the auto-text function throughout the document?
I need to execute it in all the document, it is possible?

J.Chomel